# How do you divide a time period into equal intervals and find the current one?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I need to schedule a periodic job for lots of users. This job will run at a fixed rate, the interval. I want to distribute the execution of the job for each user uniformly over that interval. For example, if the interval is 4 days, I'd use a [consistent hashing function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#consistentHash%28long,%20int%29) with an identifier for each user to schedule the job at the same time, eg. every 4 days, on the 3rd day.

The interval is relative to an origin instant that is the same for all users. Given such an origin instant, like [`Instant#EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH) or some other constant value, how do I find the start date of the current interval?

I can do

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant origin = Instant.EPOCH;
Duration interval = Duration.ofDays(4);

Duration duration = Duration.between(origin, now);
long sinceOrigin = duration.toMillis();
long millisPerInterval = interval.toMillis();

long intervalsSince = sinceOrigin / millisPerInterval;
Instant startNext = origin.plus(interval.multipliedBy(intervalsSince));

int cursor = distributionStrategy.distribute(hashCode, millisPerInterval);
```

I can then use the `cursor` to schedule the job at an `Instant` relative to the start of the current interval.

There's a lot of math here and I'm not sure the transformation to milliseconds everywhere will uphold actual dates. Is there a more precise way of dividing the time between two instants and finding the one (the subdivision) we are in currently?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. The distribution of jobs over the interval is not actually relevant to the question right? You are solely asking how to find the exact starting instant of the next interval correct?

Comment: @Zwander That's correct. Once I have the starting point, I can apply the distribution. I just wanted to indicate my end goal.

Comment: In your example, is the interval 4 logical days, or 345,600 seconds? In other words, is it a `Period` or a `Duration`?

Comment: @namshub Ideally it would be both, but let's say it's a duration.

Comment: @Pillar `Period` and `Duration` represent different concepts. If your locale observes daylight savings time, four days can be as few as 342,000 seconds or as much as 349,200 seconds.

Comment: @Namsh Right. A `Period` only deals with years, months, and days. For those units, I'd like to use `Period`. But my users may need more control, a day and a half, for example. They'd need to put 36 hours and that can only be represented as a `Duration` afaik.

Comment: @durron597 If the duration, the interval, is 60 hours, the job for the user will run every 60 hours (assuming no misses). If the distribution puts that user at the 27th hour, the job will run at time 27, time 87, and so on. I don't understand what you mean by _broken into four periods_.

Comment: @Pillar Forget what I said in my previous comment. But using your example, time 27th hour is not the same **time of day** as time 87th hour. Is that what you want? I'm trying to understand your comment to Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: @durron597 In that sense, time of day doesn't matter. If the interval is a day and a half, there's no way it can run at the same time of day. It's the periodicity I'm after.

Comment: What should happen on intervals that overlap Daylight Savings days?  Should the interval be an hour longer/shorter, or should the interval exactly respect time-since-epoch, and potentially shift over time in terms of human hours/days/etc.?

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah, forget it. I don't want to have to answer those questions. Better just keep it straight duration, even if it's not same time of day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only want to reduce the math here, you can use remainder instead of a division and multiplication.

```
long millisSinceIntervalStart = sinceOrigin % millisPerInterval;
Instant startNext = now.minusMillis(millisSinceIntervalStart);
```

Here you don't have to calculate the number of intervals passed since origin. Just get the time passed since intervalStart and subtract it from current time.

Also, your `startNext` seems to indicate the start of current interval, not the next interval. Correct?

Comment: Yes, `startNext` should be `startCurrent`. This saves an equation or two, that's good.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're *actually* interested in instants and durations (i.e. nothing to do with periods, dates, time zones etc) then your code should be fine. I'd actually go into milliseconds *earlier* in this case... the maths is all simple here.

```
Interval getInterval(Instant epoch, Duration duration, Instant now) {
    long epochMillis = epoch.getMillis();
    long durationMillis = duration.getMillis();

    long millisSinceEpoch = now.getMillis() - epochMillis;        
    long periodNumber = millisSinceEpoch / durationMillis;
    long start = epochMillis + periodNumber * durationMillis;
    return new Interval(start, start + durationMillis);
}
```

This assumes you don't need to worry about `now` being before `epoch` - at which point you'd have to do a bit of work as you want the *floor* of the division operation, rather than truncation towards 0.

(If you only want the start, you could just return `new Instant(start)`.)

Comment: Is there an easy way to reconcile periods and durations? For example, if I want to do a day and three hours, I'd like to consider the day as a day rather than 86400 seconds and append the three hours at the end.

Comment: @Pillar: Well you can create a period of "1 day and 3 hours" easily enough - but all the code for dealing with it in your use case becomes *much* more complicated at that point. You'd also need to consider that you'd sometimes have 28 hours and sometimes have 26 hours over which to distribute the work, for example... as well as specifying the time zone, which is currently irrelevant. I would strongly urge you to stick to regular durations if you possibly can.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're over-complicating things. You don't need to know nearly as much as your code suggests.

You only need to answer "when should this object next run?", such that the answer is statistically evenly distributed over the interval and consistent (not dependant on "now", except that the next run is always after "now").

This method does that:

```
public static long nextRun(long origin, long interval, Object obj) {
    long nextRunTime = origin + (System.currentTimeMillis() - origin)
       / interval * interval + Math.abs(obj.hashCode() % interval);
    return nextRunTime > System.currentTimeMillis() ? nextRunTime : nextRunTime + interval;
}
```

This method returns the next time the object should run using its `hashCode()` to determine where within the duration it should be scheduled, and then returns the next actual time that will happen.

Small implementation note: `Math.abs(obj.hashCode() % interval)` is used instead of `Math.abs(obj.hashCode()) % interval` to guard against the `hashCode()` returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and knowing that `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`

---

If you require that `java.time` classes be used in your API, here's the same code but with `java.time` parameters and return type:

```
public static Instant nextRun(Instant origin, Duration interval, Object target) {
    long start = origin.toEpochMilli();
    long width = interval.toMillis();
    long nextRunTime = start + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
       / width * width + Math.abs(target.hashCode() % width);
    nextRunTime = nextRunTime > System.currentTimeMillis() ? nextRunTime : nextRunTime + width;
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(nextRunTime);
}
```

---

To help understand the math, here's a longer version with the component calculations broken down and assigned to meaningful variable names:

```
public static Instant nextRun(Instant origin, Duration duration, Object target) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start = origin.toEpochMilli();
    long intervalWidth = duration.toMillis();
    long ageSinceOrigin = now - start;
    long totalCompleteDurations = ageSinceOrigin / intervalWidth * intervalWidth;
    long mostRecentIntervalStart = start + totalCompleteDurations;
    long offsetInDuration = Math.abs(target.hashCode() % intervalWidth);
    long nextRun = mostRecentIntervalStart + offsetInDuration;
    // schedule for next duration if this duration's time has already passed
    if (nextRun < now) { 
        nextRun += intervalWidth;
    }
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(nextRun);
}
```

Comment: Looking at just your `java.time` code (which can be reduced to `long` values), is what you propose any different than what I already have? (Other than removing intermediate variables.)

Comment: @Pillar my code doesn't know about `startNext` or `distributionStrategy`, only `origin` and `hashCode`. Also, the first version in my answer is about the smallest amount of code I can think of to get the job done (and I personally favour "less code" solutions)

Comment: That's what he meant with _removing intermediate variables_. In your last snippet, `mostRecentIntervalStart` is equivalent to `startNext` (which should be `startCurrent`)  and `hashCode` is equivalent to `distributionStrategy`.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to define each time period as an object with a start and end date.  Then use an RB Tree to store the Period objects.  Then you can navigate the tree for a specific date:

if the date is within the first period, you've found it.
if the date is before the start date of the period, navigate to the left node and check that period
if the date is after the end date of the period, navigate to the right node and check that period

Comment: I would have to keep (or recreate) multiple trees (for each job) with potentially thousands of nodes, depending on the interval size and origin date. Also, where does the tree end? Does it end at `now`? Is this really better than the math?

Comment: It is possible to buikd out a stream of intervals.. only generating enough to find the current iteration. Maybe only holding onto the last iteration where the last job instance was fired?  Perhaps also putting users into a group, calculating the trigger time for that group and applying gor the users within that group?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as has already been stated, finding the containing `Duration` interval as you are already doing or using millis directly is sufficient for this use case, and the math involved is straightforward.  However, if you did have a use case which warranted a `Period` interval involving hours, here's how it could be handled:

1. Translate the `Period` into an approximate duration of hours and use that to estimate how many intervals away the target is from the origin.
2. Scale the `Period` by your estimate.  Treat aggregations of 24 hours as additional days.
3. Move the origin interval by the scaled period.  If the moved interval contains your target, you're done.  If not, re-estimate based on the amount you missed by.

An important thing to note when finding the containing interval is that all `Period` addition must take place from the origin directly and not from intermediate intervals for consistency.  For example, if you have a `Period` of one month with an origin of January 31st, the intervals immediately after the origin interval should begin on February 28th and March 31st.  Adding two months to January 31st will correctly yield March 31st, but adding one month to February 28th would incorrectly yield March 28th.

The following is the code for the above approach.  Note that there are plenty of anomalous situations for this kind of thing, and I only tested a few of them, so don't consider this code as rigorously tested.

```
public static final int NUM_HOURS_IN_DAY = 24;
public static final int NUM_HOURS_IN_MONTH = 730;  // approximate

public ZonedDateTime startOfContainingInterval(ZonedDateTime origin, Period period, int hours, ZonedDateTime target) {
    return intervalStart(origin, period, hours, containingIntervalNum(origin, period, hours, target));
}

public int containingIntervalNum(ZonedDateTime origin, Period period, int hours, ZonedDateTime target) {
    int intervalNum = 0;
    ZonedDateTime intervalStart = origin, intervalFinish;
    long approximatePeriodHours = period.toTotalMonths() * NUM_HOURS_IN_MONTH + period.getDays() * NUM_HOURS_IN_DAY + hours;
    do {
        long gap = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(intervalStart, target);
        long estimatedIntervalsAway = Math.floorDiv(gap, approximatePeriodHours);
        intervalNum += estimatedIntervalsAway;
        intervalStart = intervalStart(origin, period, hours, intervalNum);
        intervalFinish = intervalStart(origin, period, hours, intervalNum + 1);
    } while (!(target.isAfter(intervalStart) && target.isBefore(intervalFinish) || target.equals(intervalStart)));
    return intervalNum;
}

public ZonedDateTime intervalStart(ZonedDateTime origin, Period period, int hours, int intervalNum) {
    Period scaledPeriod = period.multipliedBy(intervalNum).plusDays(hours * intervalNum / NUM_HOURS_IN_DAY);
    long leftoverHours = hours * intervalNum % NUM_HOURS_IN_DAY;
    return origin.plus(scaledPeriod).plusHours(leftoverHours);
}
```